# Eye tracking for Webcams?

Tags: hardware, webcam, tracking

So I read that Microsoft have "invented" an eye tracking webcam.
https://uk.pcmag.com/digital-camcorders/127882/microsoft-uses-ai-to-make-our-eyes-look-at-the-webcam

I would love to see this in a phone. Has anyone seen this type of thinking occur in other devices? Surely MS are not the only ones to think about this after the WFH/ Zoom revolution... eye tracking has been around for a long time, with tiny processors in Digital cameras knowing this, so it can't be hard (processing power) to do, just takes some software.

Do you know of a software or hardware combo that would allow for this?

Maybe a screen with built in camera modules behind the screen?

I know about using a mirror to create the feel, a few Youtubers showed how to build this, like this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AecAXinars

Thoughts on creating a simpler solution than buying a MS laptop please :)
Ideally I would like something that works with a monitor, or is a monitor even.

Comment: It's quite computationally expensive to do this, it's not as simple as tracking eyes & keeping them in focus, it has to rebuild the face/eye & calculate/warp a new position in realtime. [I'd like to see how well it copes if the user turns more than a few degrees from square-on;) It's likely just far less noticeable on a phone, as the distance between image & camera is smaller.

Comment: Fair comment @Tetsujin, I guess I just think of a more "rough and ready" solution that involves a simpler warp...